# cURL connecting to localhost (127.0.0.1) instead of destination IP

Tags: curl

On Mac OS X I have an issue where calling:

```
curl -v www.google.com
```

results in:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: www.google.com/
*   Trying 62.253.72.153...
* Connected to www.google.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 504 Gateway Timeout
< 
Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host
* Closing connection 0
```

The third line there is weird, because www.google.com should not be 127.0.0.1, but should be 62.253.72.153. I can't see anything weird in my network configuration. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: You may have something funky in your hosts file, or an entry in local DNS (or dns used in resolv.conf) for google.com

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. The hosts file looks fine I think: 
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
, same for the resolv.conf file (it looks fine) :/

Comment: That seems fine.  Then the issue must be in the resolver.   Try  `nslookup www.google.com`  and see what nameserver it is using.

Comment: nslookup www.google.com
Server:  10.5.13.150
Address: 10.5.13.150#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: www.google.com
Address: 62.253.72.152
Name: www.google.com
Address: 62.253.72.157
Name: www.google.com
Address: 62.253.72.173
Name: www.google.com
Address: 62.253.72.177
Name: www.google.com
Address: 62.253.72.187
Name: www.google.com
Address: 62.253.72.183
and so on :)

Comment: First question should be - are you intentionally/knowingly running a webserver at port 80?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `echo $http_proxy`

Comment: Hep pete, thanks for looking at my question. `$http_proxy` outputs nothing and I'm definitely not running a webserver at port 80 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that the Mac was in a network where the NAT wasn't configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  It would be helpful to others with a similar problem if you could elaborate a little on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked around this problem for 1 day because our gerrit server use port 8080. At last I figured it out. Hope this can help.

step 1.

```
nc -v -w 2 code.estrongs.com 8080
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif lo0
    src 127.0.0.1 port 52590
    dst 127.0.0.1 port 5001
    rank info not available
    TCP aux info available

Connection to code.estrongs.com port 8080 [tcp/http-alt] succeeded!
```

if your output looks like above, then find out what process doing stuff on port 5001

step 2.

```
nettop -nm tcp
```

looks carefully what process is handing 5001(result found by step1).

In my case is `acwebsecagent` running backgroud and forwarding all 8080 to localhost. I got rid of it by uninstall `cisco anyconnect`. Everything goes fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by antivirus (`kav`, in particular) that was passing all HTTP requests through itself as a proxy. After shutting it down the problem went away.